# Regex for HTML tags

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I'm doing the following:

```
<?
$text = preg_replace ("/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/", "$1<br>", "$text");
?>
```

So I can get rid of `<p>` tags and place a space at the end of the string (this is for styling of the page).

This works for `"<p>Something</p>"` perfectly.

However, with text like:

```
<h3>Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC</h3>
<p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
```

That I took from the Lorem Ipsum (lipsum.com) page, it doesn't work, and I don't have a clue why.

On a somehow related note (and I'm not sure if it's related enough to keep in the same question, but it could help towards this problem), is there any function or way to automatically remove every javascript snippet that these tags could have in them? 
e.g

```
<p onmouseover="alert('hello');">
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this php call:

```
$text = preg_replace('~<p\b[^>]*>(.*?)</p>~smi', "$1<br>", $text);
```

It will handle ignore case matches (`p` and `P`) as well as multi-line matches.

Answer (score 1):

There you go :

```
$text = '<h3>Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC</h3><p class="toto">"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>';


$text = preg_replace('/<p\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>/', "", $text)."<br>";
```

It also handles correctly any attribut your p might have (like a class in my example).

Answer (score 1):

There are some functions already saved in php documentation

specially this one: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#93567

```
<?php
function strip_only($str, $tags) {
if(!is_array($tags)) {
    $tags = (strpos($str, '>') !== false ? explode('>', str_replace('<', '', $tags)) : array($tags));
    if(end($tags) == '') array_pop($tags);
}
foreach($tags as $tag) $str = preg_replace('#</?'.$tag.'[^>]*>#is', '', $str);
return $str;
}

$str = '<p style="text-align:center">Paragraph</p><strong>Bold</strong><br/><span style="color:red">Red</span><h1>Header</h1>';

echo strip_only($str, array('p', 'h1'));
echo strip_only($str, '<p><h1>');
?>
```