# RegEx in PHP - as an example, replace <B> tags with <I>

Tags: php, html, regex, tags

I know next to nothing about RegEx, even after reading a few tutorials :\ I basically just want to know how to replace  tags with  tags - so how do you match the tag and how do you state that you want to replace it, keeping the tag text as it is? I saw something about a $1 in the replacement string but I don't know what that refers to?

Be as in-depth as you can, I'm brand new to this and need help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923415/regex-for-html-tags

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/). See also [How to parse HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650125/)

Comment: Dup of [Regular expression to replace an <a> with respective <img>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449759/).

Comment: Apologies if this was a duplicate, I did do a search but the stuff I found didn't quite cover it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the very simple example:

```
    $regex = '~
      <b>           #match opening <b> tag
      (.*?)         #match anything in between
      </b>          #match closing </b> tag
    ~six';

    preg_replace($regex, '<i>$1</i>', $input);
```

In this example regular expression matches opening B tag content within tag and closing B tag. Following pattern (.*?) groups content separately so you can later refer to it like $1.

If we modify expression slightly by adding more grouping parenthesis:

```
    $regex = '~
      (<b>)         #match opening <b> tag
      (.*?)         #match anything in between
      (</b>)        #match closing </b> tag
    ~six';

    preg_replace($regex, '<i>$2</i>', $input);
```

Replacement part will change from $1 to $2, as far as we have three groups we are referring to (.*?) with $2 as it's a second group etc...

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: That's exactly what I was after - so the $1, $2 etc just refers to grouped things (groups being anything in parentheses) in the match string?

Comment: Why is there `~` and `~six` and the end?

Comment: leading and trailing ~ character is required for indicating start and end of the expression. "six" means: "s" enables new line matching, "i" means case insensitive and "x" means we can put comments inside regular expression.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to look at some tutorial Videos, since reading them obviously didn't help, I could imagine that answering how to replace `<B>` with `<I>` wouldn't help neither.

Here is video tutorial on youtube for example: [Regular Expression Tutorials Part # 1 for PHP - Javascript](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXwgTzBUAXo)